# Browser detection code detects Edge as Chrome

Tags: javascript

My browser detection code is something like this

```
   navigator.sayswho = (function () {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var tem;
        var M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
        if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
            tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
            return 'IE ' + (tem[1] || '');
        }
        if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
            tem = ua.match(/\b(OPR|Edge)\/(\d+)/);
            if (tem != null) return tem.slice(1).join(' ').replace('OPR', 'Opera');
        }
        M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
        if ((tem = ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
        return M.join(' ');
    })();

    alert(navigator.sayswho); // outputs: `Chrome 62`

});
```

All looks good but on edge this code returns browser as "Chrome". How can I fix this?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Have you checked what `navigator.userAgent` contains? Also, what's the expected output?

Comment: Why do you need to tell apart Edge and Chrome? They're both based on the same Chromium project. Most features should behave exactly the same.

Comment: If you want to detect Edge, you should be checking ```"Edg"``` instead of ```"Edge"```.

Answer (score 2):

Usually I put Edge check on top to pass this. When you try to see

**userAgent in chrome**: *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36'*

**userAgent in Edge**:  *Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; ServiceUI 14) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19041*

Even in Edge it contains chrome before the Edge. Used below code to check this normally check for Edge before chrome.

```
function fnBrowserDetect(){
                 
         let userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
         let browserName;
           if(userAgent.match(/edg/i)){
             browserName = "edge";
           }
         else if(userAgent.match(/chrome|chromium|crios/i)){
             browserName = "chrome";
           }else if(userAgent.match(/firefox|fxios/i)){
             browserName = "firefox";
           }  else if(userAgent.match(/safari/i)){
             browserName = "safari";
           }else if(userAgent.match(/opr\//i)){
             browserName = "opera";
           }else{
             browserName="No browser detection";
           }
         
          return "You are using "+ browserName +" browser";         
  }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate this answer with how to check browser version too

Answer (score 0):

Basically you're currently using the legacy method to detect the user client. New Standard recommend to use the `navigator.userAgentData.brands` to detect the actual browser client name either it's chrome or edge.
You can see it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/web-platform/user-agent-guidance) for edge.
You can also check out the official docs of mdn for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/userAgentData) purpose.